# "Duplicate method" error when using Hibernate + Javassist + Gilead

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, gwt, gilead

My web app is using GWT 2.0.2, GXT 2.1.1, Hibernate 3.5-CR1, Javassist 3.11.0 and Gilead 1.3.1 (latest from SVN).

My app was running just fine with GWT 1.7.1 + Gilead 1.2.

I want to take advantage of some of the features of GWT 2.0, and figured I'd upgrade to the latest Gilead in the process.  I pointed to the new gwt.xml file in Gilead 1.3.  I'm also using the new net.sf.gilead.pojo.gwt.LightEntity instead of net.sf.gilead.pojo.java5.LightEntity.

I have a few Hibernate entities/classes that extend **LightEntity** (i.e. Question, Form), as well as a few more entities/classes that extend the Question entity.  Not sure if it matters, but I'm using InheritanceType.JOINED for the inheritance strategy in the Question entity.

For reference, here's the Question class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Questions")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Question extends LightEntity implements IsSerializable,
        IFormItem, Comparable<Question> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9180458948973980161L;

    public static final String FIELD_NAME_PREFIX = "field_"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private static final String REQUIRED_QUESTION = "<span style=\"color: red;\">*</span>"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    public static int MIN_WIDTH = 50;
    public static int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 200;
    public static int MAX_WIDTH = 600;

    private int id;
    private Integer questionOrder;
    private String questionNumber;
    protected String questionText;
    protected boolean required;
    private String toolTip;
    protected Integer fieldWidth;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isRequired() {
        return this.required;
    }

    public void setRequired(boolean required) {
        this.required = required;
    }

    public String getToolTip() {
        return this.toolTip;
    }

    public void setToolTip(String toolTip) {
        this.toolTip = toolTip;
    }

    @Column(length = 5000)
    @Lob
    public String getQuestionText() {
        return this.questionText;
    }

    public void setQuestionText(String pText) {
        this.questionText = pText;
    }

    public Integer getQuestionOrder() {
        return this.questionOrder;
    }

    public void setQuestionOrder(Integer questionOrder) {
        this.questionOrder = questionOrder;
    }

    public String getQuestionNumber() {
        return this.questionNumber;
    }

    public void setQuestionNumber(String questionNumber) {
        this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
    }

    public boolean hasQuestionNumber() {
        return getQuestionNumber() != null
                && !getQuestionNumber().trim().isEmpty();
    }

    public Integer getFieldWidth() {
        return this.fieldWidth;
    }

    public void setFieldWidth(Integer fieldWidth) {
        this.fieldWidth = fieldWidth;
    }

    public Component render(FormPanel formPanel, int order, int questionSpacing) {
        final Component c = generateWidget(getId());
        if (c instanceof Field<?>) {
            final Field<?> field = (Field<?>) c;
            field.setLabelSeparator(FormBuilderConstants.EMPTY_TEXT);
            field.setValidateOnBlur(true);
            field.setAutoValidate(true);
            field.setName(FIELD_NAME_PREFIX.concat(String.valueOf(getId())));
            if (getToolTip() != null) {
                field.setToolTip(getToolTip());
            }

            final FormData formData;
            if (field instanceof SimpleComboBox<?>) {
                formData = new FormData();
            } else {
                if (getFieldWidth() == null) {
                    field.setAutoWidth(true);
                    formData = new FormData(FormBuilderConstants.FORM_ANCHOR_SPEC);
                } else {
                    field.setWidth(getFieldWidth().intValue());
                    field.setAutoWidth(false);

                    formData = new FormData(getFieldWidth().intValue(), -1);
                }
            }

            final String questionNumber;
            if (this.questionNumber != null && !this.questionNumber.isEmpty()) {
                questionNumber = this.questionNumber;
            } else {
                questionNumber = String.valueOf(order);
            }

            if (this.answerable()) {
                String displayQuestionText = questionNumber.concat(". ") //$NON-NLS-1$
                        .concat(getQuestionText());
                if (isRequired()) {
                    displayQuestionText = displayQuestionText
                            .concat(REQUIRED_QUESTION);
                }

                field.setFieldLabel(displayQuestionText);
            }

            field.setIntStyleAttribute("margin-bottom", questionSpacing); //$NON-NLS-1$

            formPanel.add(field, formData);
        } else {
            formPanel.add(c);
        }

        return c;
    }

    protected abstract Component generateWidget(final int id);

    public abstract String questionType();

    public int compareTo(final Question q) {
        return this.questionOrder.intValue() - q.questionOrder.intValue();
    }

    public boolean answerable() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My app has a startup servlet that creates a Hibernate session factory. In the logs, I get a "duplicate method" error on all of the classes that directly or indirectly extend LightEntity.  I wonder if this is an issue with Javassist's handling of inheritance.

```
16:32:59,616 DEBUG AbstractEntityPersister:2773 -  Identity insert: insert into Questions (fieldWidth, questionNumber, questionOrder, questionText, required, toolTip) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
16:32:59,619 ERROR BasicLazyInitializer:165 - Javassist Enhancement failed: com.function1.formbuilder.client.model.Question
java.lang.RuntimeException: duplicate method: getProxyInformation in com.function1.formbuilder.client.model.Question_$$_javassist_5
     at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:344)
     at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:314)
     at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:273)
     at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:162)
     at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:66)
     at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:188)
     at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:151)
     at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:78)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
     at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:107)
     at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
     at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:80)
     at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:323)
     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:456)
     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.<init>(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:113)
     at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:87)
     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:267)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1341)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
     at com.function1.common.F1HibernateUtil.<clinit>(F1HibernateUtil.java:22)
     at com.function1.formbuilder.server.StartupServlet.init(StartupServlet.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: duplicate method: getProxyInformation in com.function1.formbuilder.client.model.Question_$$_javassist_0
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:344)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:314)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:162)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.DuplicateMemberException: duplicate method: getProxyInformation in com.function1.formbuilder.client.model.Question_$$_javassist_0
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.testExistingMethod(ClassFile.java:593)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.addMethod(ClassFile.java:577)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.override(ProxyFactory.java:658)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.overrideMethods(ProxyFactory.java:632)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.make(ProxyFactory.java:552)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:335)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: give the whole code of `Question`

Comment: I added the whole code, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Try temporarily getting rid of all classes that extend Question, make question concrete, and remove all inheritance mappings, and see whether the exception persists. Then give feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As illustrated by [ticket HIBERNATE-37](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/HIBERNATE-37), somehow `getProxyInformation()` gets define twice, possibly with a different return type.

[ticket HHH-1938](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1938) suggested using [**cglib**](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) instead of JavaAssist as a bytecode enhancer, but I an not sure if this is possible in your configuration.

> You must change the value of

```
hibernate.bytecode.provider=javassist
```

> for

```
hibernate.bytecode.provider=cglib
```

> in:

```
<WHERE IS YOUR JBOSS>\server\default\deploy\ejb3.deployer\META-INF\ persistence.properties
```

> And that fixes the problem of duplicated method

(again, this is not your configuration but that could give you an idea where to look)

Answer (score 1):

The new javassist versoin 3.16.1-GA will work with duplicate methods:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JASSIST-127

And there were some other similar issues also fixed for 3.16.0-GA

Answer (score 0):

Javassist doesn't allow duplicate methods (allowed by Java5)

https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JASSIST-24

Try removing `Comparable<Question>` if that is possible.